# Cannot run jflex in shell

Tags: java, bash, shell, flex-lexer, jflex

I have already successfully installed jflex, however when I try to execute a file named "commentaire.flex", I use the command

```
    jflex commentaire.flex
```

as what is told in http://jflex.de/manual.html#installing-jflex, but the terminal give back

```
    -bash: jflex: command not found
```

So how can I run the .flex file with jflex generater

Comment: where did jflex get installed? Is it in a directory that is in your $PATH?

Comment: in the same directory with my .flex file

Comment: do I need to change my $PATH?

Comment: Better is to leave your path as is, and put jflex in a directory in your path. (~/bin is usually in your path, for example.)

Comment: @rici Sorry I didn't quite get you. What do you mean by 'putting jflex in a directory in your path'?

Comment: `jflex` is a file. Since it is an executable utility, it should be in some directory used to hold executable utilities. These firectories are listed in your `PATH`. So I am suggesting that you move it to such a directory.

Comment: I've changed my CLASSPATH to the directory of lib/jflex-1.6.1.jar, but it still cannot work. The terminal keeps saying jflex: command not found

Comment: That errot is about PATH, not CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

jflex compiles in bash with the command

```
  java jflex.Main <filename>
```

but you have to change your CLASSPATH first